# how to Live Video Stream into ios app from server continually using Http live streaming.

Tags: ios, objective-c, video-streaming, video-capture, http-live-streaming

Please answer would be developer prospective.
I m new to ios networking based iphone application. 
      I m want to make live video watching iphone app through server which can have live video.
      It is possible through Http live streaming using web server.
My Question is how to make it possible through ios programming and I already read HLS doc but I can not understand to make thing possible.
if u can give me links or tell me exact solution it would be more benificial for me.

Please help.Thanks